# I would like to sum the all of the colums in an alias called "totals" for my oracle sql code below

Tags: sql, oracle

This code counts the  number of EPV.SITE_AB per month (The extract statement is just pulling the month from the date in that field). What I need is another field that shows the total of all fields (jan,Feb, Mar etc.) that populates alias field named "Annual Total".
I am fairly green in sql coding, so the information that I had seen on this and other sites, went over my head.

```
SELECT 
'ABLATIONS' as Procedures,
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),1,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Jan",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),2,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Feb",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),3,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Mar",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),4,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Apr",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),5,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "May",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),6,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Jun",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),7,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Jul",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),8,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Aug",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),9,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Sep",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),10,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Oct",
count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),11,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Nov",
COUNT(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),12,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Dec"
FROM APEX_DATA.EP_VISIT EPV 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT) = 2010 --Ablations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT 'ABLATIONS' AS PROCEDURES,
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),1,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Jan",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),2,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Feb",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),3,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Mar",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),4,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Apr",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),5,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "May",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),6,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Jun",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),7,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Jul",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),8,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Aug",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),9,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Sep",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),10,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Oct",
       count(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),11,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Nov",
       COUNT(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT),12,EPV.SITE_ABL)) AS "Dec",
       COUNT(EPV.SITE_ABL) AS "Annual Total"
  FROM APEX_DATA.EP_VISIT EPV
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EPV.ADMIT_DT) = 2010
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include all the columns from your original query as well as the new one.

Comment: That would be great if I were looking to sum just one month, this is a count of all twelve months which my code does. The output looks like this Ablations Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec                   2   4   3   5   0   0   0   1   3   0   10 
5

I would like to have a grand total.

Comment: @avalon07 Please put additional info in your question (you can *edit* it) instead of posting it as a comment.